# Can a Xamarin Forms ListView button be customised on a per-row basis?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

On a Xamarin Forms page I have the following working code for a ListView:

```
listView = new ListView (ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement);
listView.ItemsSource = labelInfoList;
listView.ItemTapped += OnGroupTapped;
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => 
{
    nameLabel = new Label ();
    nameLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Label");
    ViewCell viewCell = new ViewCell ();
    MenuItem observeAction = new MenuItem {Text = "Observe"};
    observeAction.SetBinding (MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding ("."));
    observeAction.Clicked += async (sender, e) => { ... };
    viewCell.ContextActions.Add (observeAction);
    viewCell.View = new StackLayout 
    {
        Padding = new Thickness (0, 5),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Children = { nameLabel }
    };
    return viewCell;
});
```

When I swipe left on a list item, a button appears, labelled "Observe". So far, so good.

What I would like now is to replace the string "Observe" with a string derived from the corresponding element of labelInfoList, so that the button label is more customized to the row in question. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MenuItem.Text` is a bindable property, so I am thinking something like this could work:

```
observeAction.SetBinding (MenuItem.TextProperty, new Binding ("SomeParameter"));
```

You might combine this with a `IValueConverter` to change what the text says based on the binding context value.